# How to make listView with multiple clickable textViews

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

I am new to android programming. I am working on android app and I have a listview with multiple textViews out of that 2 textViews are Clickable. If user clicks on 'phone' textView it should call to that number and if user clicks on 'street_address' textView it should route it with google maps. Following is my code of my adapter class

```
class ListViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView street_address;
    TextView phone;
    TextView distance;
    ListViewHolder(View v)
    {
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        street_address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
        phone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    }
}

public class ListDisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context mcontext = null;
    public List<NameAddress> listData;

    public ListDisplayAdapter(Context context, List<NameAddress> list)
    {
        mcontext = context;
        this.listData = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) 
    {
        return listData.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) 
    {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
    {
        View row = view;
        ListViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
            holder=new ListViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        NameAddress data = listData.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(data.getName());
        holder.phone.setText(data.getPhone());
        holder.street_address.setText(data.toString());
        holder.distance.setText(data.getDistance());
        return row;

    }

}
```

Following is hte code of activity class

```
public class ListDisplayActivity extends Activity 
{

    ListView listView;
    public String tag_name; 
    public List<NameAddress> nameAddressList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_display);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent!= null)
        {
            tag_name = intent.getStringExtra("DashItemName");
        }

        nameAddressList = null;
        try 
        {
            XMLDOMParserHandler parser = new XMLDOMParserHandler(tag_name);
            nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(getAssets().open("data.xml"));
            ListDisplayAdapter listAdapter = new ListDisplayAdapter(this, nameAddressList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Please tell me how can I code this

Comment: Where is your onClickListener? You need to attach them to your text view. You could pass your data object (NameAddress) into your holder to and initialize your text view + setup onclick in one shot.

Comment: @rootstertech I tried attaching onClickListner to texView, but when i'm using intent inside it for starting activity it is giving error.

Comment: @roostertech is right, you need to attach OnClickListeners. What error are you getting?

Comment: @roostertech The method startActivity() is undefined for the type ListViewHolder

Comment: @Akshay, startActivity has to be call on a context. You have the context in your adapter, pass it into your view holder.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public class ListDisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context mcontext = null;
    public List<NameAddress> listData;

    public ListDisplayAdapter(Context context, List<NameAddress> list)
    {
        mcontext = context;
        this.listData = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) 
    {
        return listData.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) 
    {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
    {
        View row = view;
        ListViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
holder = new ListViewHolder();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
             name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.street_address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
        holder.phone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        holder.distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        NameAddress data = listData.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(data.getName());
        holder.phone.setText(data.getPhone());
holder.phone.settag(data.getPhone());
        holder.street_address.setText(data.toString());
holder.street_address.settag(data.toString());
        holder.distance.setText(data.getDistance());

 holder.phone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            String phoneno = ((Textview)v).gettag();
    }
});

holder.street_address.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            String streetaddress = ((Textview)v).gettag();
    }
});
        return row;

    }

class ListViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView street_address;
    TextView phone;
    TextView distance;
}


}
```